# Save Errors in Problems tab Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, compiler-errors

I know we can see the syntax error when we run a project or a class.

but i want to catch the compile error when we BUILD a project.

is there a way to catch the errors and save it to a textfile? or even read the errors in the Problem tab.

[image: See pic here]

Thank you!!

Comment: hi, please read here -> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question :)

Comment: Errors appear in the Problems view appear when a file is saved not when it is run. Plugins can access the errors since they are markers.

Comment: The Eclipse Java compiler is also available separately to run on the command line: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.8-201806110500/#JDTCORE

Comment: @greg-449 maybe you know some ways to catch theses errors?

Comment: I am looking for a way to catch these errors Programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Problems view shows error markers. These are objects implementing the `IMarker` interface with a type of `IMarker.PROBLEM`.

You can access these markers in an Eclipse plugin. Given an `IFile` (or any `IResource`) you can get the markers on the file using

```
IFile file = ....

IMarker [] markers = file.getMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_ONE);
```

Comment: i am new to this sorry. but can you help me with the IFile file = ...? The import org.eclipse.core.resources cannot be resolved. IFile cannto be resolved to a type. what is next to =. what should i put there?

Comment: This code must be in an Eclipse plugin, it won't work in a plain Java program. You need to add `org.eclipse.core.resources` to the plugin's dependencies. I can't tell you what '...' should be because it depends on where you are running this code.

Comment: how can i get the result sync with my existing eclipse? its like i need to build twice to get the correct error number.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Ask a new question showing what you have done.